# Error in submitting List of objects to apache-cxf jax-rs (REST) service

Tags: json, cxf, jax-rs

I want to post List of Customers in JSON in the following way:

```
@POST
@Path("/addCustomers/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Customer> addCustomers(List<Customer> list){
logger.debug(list);
    return list;
}

Request Header:
Content-Type: application/json

Request Body:
{"Customer":[{"id":2999,"name":"Som Awasthi"},{"id":3000,"name":"Arnav Awasthi"}]}

Response: "415: Unsupported Media Type" error.
```

Input to this request is same, what I have got in the listCustomers call, which is as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/listCustomers")
public List<Customer> listCustomers(){
List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
list.add(new Customer("Som Awasthi", 2999L));
list.add(new Customer("Arnav Awasthi", 3000L));

return list;
}
```

So I expected that input should give me List object. But it is giving me Unsupported Media Type error.

Regards,
Arnav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution through one discussion in nabble:

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-submit-JSON-data-as-request-body-in-Apache-CXF-jax-rs-REST-td4361669.html

Summary is:
Apache-CXF 2.3.0 and Jettison 1.2 doesn't support this. So I had to change the version to 2.3.4 and it worked.

Sample Application:
https://bitbucket.org/arnavawasthi/apache-cxf-jaxrs-spring

Hope that will help the others facing the same problem.

Thanks,
Arnav

Comment: can you look at this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863262/nosuchmethoderror-creating-rest-service

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an Accept header to your request:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Also, make sure your request is definitely a POST.

EDIT:

So the json you are passing in is an object with an array inside. Try passing this in which is an array of customer objects:

```
[{"id":2999,"name":"Som Awasthi"},{"id":3000,"name":"Arnav Awasthi"}]
```

Comment: I added Accept: application/json, still the same error. When I changed Content-Type to appliction/xml and kept Accept: application/json. Now instead of json I passed equivalent XML and changed server side @Consume to @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML}). Now the response is: {"Customer":[{"id":2999,"name":"Som Awasthi"},{"id":3000,"name":"Arnav Awasthi"},{"id":3001,"name":"Arnav"}]}. But inverse of this is not working. Not sure if unmarshalling of JSON array is causing this issue.

Comment: This approach is working for one object. Example if I submit Customer object in json form, it works. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844394/how-to-submit-json-data-as-request-body-in-apache-cxf-jax-rs-rest. But if submit array of objects it doesn't.