# NoSuchMethodError: Creating rest service

Tags: rest, cxf

I have written a JAX-RS service with following auto created interface from the wadl configuration. But I am landing into following issue. What can be the cause of this error? The service is running for single Play object, the Path params but not for ArrayOfPlay. I am able to send an ArrayOfPlay from the server to client but facing this trouble while sending from client to server.

```
 @Path("/play")
 public interface PlayService {


@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json" })
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json" })
@Path("/post")
Response postUpdate(ArrayOfPlay arrayofplay);

 }
```

---

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
    at javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.<init>(InternalServerErrorException.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toInternalServerErrorException(SpecExceptions.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toInternalServerErrorException(ExceptionUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.convertExceptionToResponseIfPossible(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:226)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
```

- CXF version: 3.1.0

  **ArrayOfPlay**

  ```
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "play"
  })
  @XmlRootElement(name = "ArrayOfPlay")
   public class ArrayOfPlay
  implements Serializable
   {

   private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @XmlElement(name = "Play", required = true)
   protected List<Play> play;

   public List<Play> getPlay() {
  if (play == null) {
      play = new ArrayList<Play>();
  }
  return this.play;
  }

  }
  ```

Update: If I send a List instead of ArrayOfPlay I am able to make it work. How to represent as List in wadl? The current representation is:

```
<representation mediaType="application/xml" element="ns:ArrayOfPlay"/>
```

Comment: what is the cxf version you have ?

Comment: This issue was resolver in 2.7.11,not sure but can you try with adding asm 3.3.1 and jettison 1.3.3

Comment: already having both but higher versions.