# how to send multiple same objects using json in java?

Tags: java

i write java code for sending multiple json same objects in java as below..

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private int prize;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPrize() {
        return prize;
    }
    public void setPrize(int prize) {
        this.prize = prize;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Books {
List<Book> books;

public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}

}
```

---

```
@Path("books")
public interface BookIntf {
    @Path("/book")
    @POST
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    @Consumes({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    public Response addBooks(Books books);
}
```

---

```
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookIntf {

    public Response addBooks(Books books) {
        String status = null;
        JSONObject soapDatainJsonObject = null;
        String jsontext = null;
        try {

                BookDao iotdao = new BookDao();
                status = iotdao.addBooks(books);



        } catch (Exception localException) {
            status = "failed in Service layer";
        }
        return Response.ok().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(jsontext).build();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BookDao {
    public String addBooks(Books books) {
        Session aoSession = MDHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction addObjectTx = null;
        String XMLStatusString = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {

            addObjectTx = aoSession.beginTransaction();
            List inPutAnalytics = books.getBooks();
            Iterator itrIPAnalytics = inPutAnalytics.iterator();
            while (itrIPAnalytics.hasNext()) {
                Book iotAnalyticPOJO = (Book) itrIPAnalytics.next();


                String bookName = iotAnalyticPOJO.getName();
                int price = iotAnalyticPOJO.getPrize();

                System.out.println("bookName:"+bookName); 
                System.out.println("price: "+price);



            }




        } catch (Exception localexception) {
            if (addObjectTx != null)
                addObjectTx.rollback();


        } finally {
            aoSession.close();
        }
        return XMLStatusString;
    }
}
```

---

can you please tell me is their any mistakes in above code. and url for that is:-
     http://localhost:8081/Smarter/services/books/book

### Request Body:-

```
{
  "books": 
    [
      {
       "name":"mani",
        "prize":120
      },
      {
        "name":"nani",
        "prize":1240
      }
    ]
  }
```

---

The Error is 415 Unsupported Media Type...

can you please tell me how to pass multiple same objects in java using json.
Thanks..

Comment: no errors in your code. How do you post your request ? your client should add http header `Content-Type` with `application/json`, to tell the server what type your body is. so spring mvc can consume it.

Comment: Hi meng, i am sending request thought POSTMAN,and i am using org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.

Comment: With Postman, in the Headers option, try to add a header parameter : KEY is `Content-Type` and VALUE is `application/json`, and then send the request maybe ok.

Comment: yes meng, i have allreday did this, but, i am getting 415 nsupported Media Type

Comment: If so, I think you are missing the configuration of JSONProvider.

Comment: Ya,Thanks @meng ,my problem was solved through  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844394/how-to-submit-json-data-as-request-body-in-apache-cxf-jax-rs-rest .                                                                                                           Just I added jettison library to resolve this issue.